# VSTO ToggleButton "press" manually

Tags: c#, xml, vsto

I have c# VSTO project with XML ribbon. I have 5 toggle buttons in one group, I would like to make them work as a "group". For example Add-In loaded with toggle1 pressed, if I press toggle2 then toggle1 is unpressed and so on. In other way i need to unpress buttons manualy. It's simple in my mind but I can't find any solution or way to make it. Maybe its not supported?

```
<group id="myToggle"..>
<togglebutton id="toggle1" onAction="Click1" getPressed="Click_Pressed" ...>
<togglebutton id="toggle2" onAction="Click2" getPressed="Click_Pressed" ...>
<togglebutton id="toggle3" onAction="Click3" getPressed="Click_Pressed" ...>
.. 
</group>

Public bool Click_Pressed(IRibbonControl control)
{
    return Toggle1Bool;  
}
Public void Click1(ref IRibbonControl control, bool flip)
...
```

EDITED: seems it was an easy. I had everything right here, and on my original code i did small mistake in typing, that's why I could not manage to achieve this.

All I need is to update "Toggle1Bool" true/false and then use Ribbon.Invalidate() to update whole ribbon or InvalidateControl to update specific ribbon item.

If user pressing same button twice or its already pressed "bool flip" comes as false, so I just have to check IF and set Toggle1Bool again True and update ribbon.

Problem solved. Don't know how to mark answered. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Use a radio button and put the button into a group box.

Comment: @jdweng how to make groupbox on VSTO xml ?

Comment: The buttons have to be in a group.  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/ribbon-xml?view=vs-2019

Comment: @jdweng ah oh you mean simple "group" :), it's a small solution. But I prefer to use buttons with pressed effect (background) rather radio buttons. There is no way to press/unpress button manually ?

Comment: @jdweng there is no Radio buttons on Ribbon UI...

Answer (score 0):

You would have to figure out each button's state in your code and update them explicitly in your code by refreshing the ribbon.